# UDP, datagrams and sound in java

Tags: java, audio, udp

I need an example code of sending UDP sound packets, like using datagrams to send audio from server, who record the audio by the microphone, to a client, who only listen the audio. Can someone help me please?
*I have found really good examples, but they all use TCP and Sockets (like this one http://www.developer.com/java/other/print.php/2105421), not DatagramSocket, i would really appreciate your help.*

Comment: The link you mentioned was really helpful for me, i was looking for some core java code without external dependency but didn't had much luck, this was a good tutorial :)

Comment: Have a Look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html  Especially the section about writing client and server datagram.

Answer (score 3):

Sending via UDP is a bit silly. UDP can arrive in any order and has no sequencing in the protocol. This means you may or may not receive a packet and you may receive packet two before one and have no way of knowing (without having written some code to sequence them) which is first.

Drop UDP and use TCP.

EDIT:

Okay assuming you must use UDP then roughly I would do it like this (assuming you can send a UDP packet)

1) create scheme of data to be encapsulated in UDP of the following data

Packet sequence number
Data
Crc checksum

2) on the clientside you will need a buffer to order and reassemble the data

This will buffer the packets, order and at a given buffer length reassemble the data (either inserting no audio or truncating where missing sequence numbers are)

You would need to have also worked out what the bit rate is considering the weakest connection. It is better to lose granularity of sound than have very clear snippets of sound.

Note. The crc could also be combined with data length.

Hth

Comment: I already have the code on TCP and i would like to leave it that way, but i have to use UDP because is recommended for audio sending, and i was ask UDP especially, so i need an example of sending audio using UDP if anyone have one.

Comment: @CarollMitchel, Ask yourself: Why is that recommended? If you are out for reducing latency, then it might be needed, but you'll run into the problems described above. There shouldn't be _that_ big a difference code-wise unless you try to implement packet retransmissions and ordering (in which case you're basically back to TCP anyway).

Comment: As simon said you will just end up rewriting a sequencing algorithm creating a software TCP stack or accept lossy and garbled audio. If your client has asked you to do it in UDP then advise them it would be a very bad idea for the described reasons.

Comment: @PaulSullivan, but that does not answer his question? Im also very interested to know how would one accomplish this task.

Comment: @JohnyDep agreed not an answer but why the need for UDP?

Comment: UDP is faster than TCP, in this case we need to implement that over audio recording, we appreciate any time we could save, and we can afford losing some data

Comment: @PaulSullivan, because there is no acknowledgement involved so the overhead is less and you don't care if some packets are lost. Essentially all voip/Skype uses UDP for voice chat, so OP's question is pretty valid.

Comment: Ludicrous. If the data is stored on the client before transmission over TCP you will lose nothing there will just be lag before it reaches the server.

Comment: Okay ack joke about three way handshake being overhead

Comment: I did not talk about 3-Way handshake, by overhead i mean for each packet in TCP you have to acknowledge it's reception while for UDP you don't acknowledge anything, and this indeed saves a lot of overhead. All IM's over internet use UDP for voice chat, for the same reason.

Comment: I´m really new at this, i would like you to add examples if you could

Answer (score 0):

Give these Links a try:

1. [Simplistic Java music broadcasting over UDP](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.bilgi.edu.tr/~mgencer/Ders%2520Malzemeleri/IThingTaggedFile/MusicBroadcast.java&ei=xrcvT7HUC4bBtAaJlrT5BQ&usg=AFQjCNGDw580MTABeS9FKTIRh5tBxywJdw)
2. [TCP/IP, UDP & Multicasting Through Java's Socket](http://www.calsoftlabs.com/whitepapers/java-networking.html)
3. Check this [Interactive Telephony Article](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/redial/week12.html), specially the [Streaming Class Example](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/redial/JEAGIStreamer.java)

And then read little about [DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) Class in Java. [This tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)l should definitively help.